# How can i limit hours in date field?

Tags: datetime

I have a reservation form with entityForm and i want to limit hours in date field.
like it begins 3:00 till 9:00 .
i've searched a lot and use [Date Restrictions](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_restrictions) module but i couldn't do this .
Any idea would be appreciate it ?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your date field, I don't know an easy way. But if you take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/office_hours, it would create a new field allowing custom hours. Maybe combining both fields you could do the trick.

Comment: thx,but it's not what i'm looking for